# Building Tri-Tree based on Preorder Ordering List

Tags: python, list, recursion, tree

I am preparing for an exam and have some difficulty solving this question:

> Build a tri-tree given a list called `preorder_list`, providing the preorder sequence of that tri-tree.

For example, the tree could be:

[image]

R stands for the Root, NV stands for the No Value node and the integers are the Leaf nodes.

So my interpretation is that the preorder list based on the above tree is the following:

```
[R, R, R, NV, 4, 9, 10, R, 11, NV, 12, R, 13, 14, R, 15, 16, 17, R, 
 R, NV, 18, 19, R, 20, 21, R, 22, 23, NV, R, 24, R, 25, NV, 26, 27]
```

Below is the code that I currently have:

```
class SubtreeRoot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = [None, None, None]


class LeafNode:
    def __init__(self, value : int):
        self.value = value


class NoValueNode:
    def __init__(self):
        pass


def build_tri_tree_from_preorder_list(preorder_list : List[]) -> SubtreeRoot:
    if preorder_list[0] == "R":
        r = SubtreeRoot()
        return r
    else:
        pass
```

I have a problem in the recursive case. I decided to use a top-down approach (starting from the top-most root and recurse down), but I am not sure how to determine the following three subtrees. For example, where does each subtree start in the preorder_list?

How can I implement the recursion so that it will deal with the lower subtrees?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible implementation:

```
def build_tri_tree_from_preorder_list(preorder_list : List) -> SubtreeRoot:
    it = iter(preorder_list)

    def recur():
        label = next(it)
        if label == "R":
            r = SubtreeRoot()
            r.children[:] = recur(), recur(), recur()
            return r
        elif label == "NV":
            return NoValueNode()
        else:
            return LeafNode(label)

    return recur()
```

It would be nicer though if the constructor for `SubtreeRoot` would accept the children as arguments:

```
class SubtreeRoot:
    def __init__(self, left=None, mid=None, right=None):
        self.children = [left, mid, right]
```

And then the function can be:

```
def build_tri_tree_from_preorder_list(preorder_list : List) -> SubtreeRoot:
    it = iter(preorder_list)

    def recur():
        label = next(it)
        if label == "R":
            return SubtreeRoot(recur(), recur(), recur())
        elif label == "NV":
            return NoValueNode()
        else:
            return LeafNode(label)

    return recur()
```

Also, be aware that the return type specification of your function may be too optimistic. A preorder list could be just ["L"] or [15], and then the returned value will be a `NoValueNode` or `LeafNode` instead of a `SubtreeNode`.

Comment: Could you please give some feed-back?